# Lubuntu 13.04: Copying from MTP device (Nexus 4) gives file names with numbers

Tags: linux, lubuntu, mtp

I'm running Lubuntu 13.04 and the MTP device in question is a Google/LG Nexus 4.

My computer is finding the phone with no problem and asks me what to do when I plug it in. I can browse the phone's storage and everything's there. However, if I drag files from it to my filesystem, the copied files and directories are all named with numbers instead of the names (I'm guessing these are the files' StorageIDs?), whereas the files are being rendered in Pcmanfm with their filenames.

Does anyone know of a way to get these files to copy to my filesystem with their filenames intact? I'm trying to bring in my music library but Audacious isn't smart enough to recognize the music files unless they have a proper extension. No way am I manually renaming every folder and file in my music library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found post #3 at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119633 to work for me:

There is a recent problem with newer android versions no longer automatically mounting properly. Have searched so far and wide as to install this ppa? https://launchpad.net/~langdalepl/+archive/gvfs-mtp

That solved it for me.

Try it out.

Comment: This post is not very useful, in case the forums go down (yet again). Summarize the main points of the thread, then post a link just as the source